# Map Page Up, Page Down and Num Lock just for Excel with Autohotkey

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I would like to map these keys to the corresponding text:

Page Up (

Page Down )

Num Lock =

I want to do this with Autohotkey but I'm having a hard time figuring out the script. 
I also only want to do this in excel.

I know I need to add #IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN

Answer (score 1):

You can either use SetTitleMatchMode, 2 and use a part of the window title like:  Excel, or your solution with #IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN ; Start the Excel specific section
PgUp::Send, {(}
PgDn::Send, {)}
NumLock::Send, {=}
#IfWinActive , ; Close the Excel specific section
```